# ASP.NET Core 2.1 in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Preview 15.7

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I installed VS 2017 Preview 15.7.0 Preview 3.0 however Asp.net core 2.1 still missing in the dropdown list when creating New ASP.NET Core Web Application.

[image]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed it. use 2.1.300 instead

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview1

[image]

Comment: .net core 2.1.300 is also the right version to install with visual studio 15.7.2